# Pop a viewController which has asnyc task, will it destory before the task finish in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, destroy

When I pop my `viewcontroller`, in it's `viewWillDisappear` method,I localize the `viewcontroller`'s data to `sandbox`,and will the localization finish then system destroy `viewcontroller`?

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    // localization method
    [self localDataToSandbox];
}

- (void)localDataToSandbox {

    if (self.buyDataSource.count > 0) {

        NSMutableArray *arr_tmp;

        if (self.buyDataSource.count > 20) {
            arr_tmp = [[self.buyDataSource subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 20)] mutableCopy];
        }else {
            arr_tmp = self.buyDataSource;
        }

        CacheManager *manager = [CacheManager sharedManager];
        [manager cacheModelArray:arr_tmp toPath:[Util getTmpDirectory] withName:buy_cache];
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

As we know, if `vc1` push to `vc2`, and `vc2` pop to `vc1`, the `vc2` will be recycled by system.

my question is if when `vc2` pop to `vc1`, will the method in `viewWillDisappear` interrupt?

Comment: ...? I do not understand this question

Comment: That depends on whether `self` is captured by the task.  Since you didn't show the code, we can't answer that.

Comment: @Avi I have updated my question, did you mean if `self` captured by the method, it will not be destroyed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `localDataToSandbox` would have a closure/block that captures `self`, it would be invoked back to that closure while in the other case (your case -  when you **wouldn't** have that closure to capture self), it would be **removed** from the stack nav hierarchy and there is no guaranty that 
`localDataToSandbox` will finish its actual runtime.

Meaning, using a closure would solve your issue and **self** would be captured.

Comment: I don't think that would solve the problem, as if you have some reference to something you used in the self, you could end up trying to access a nil, and that would be a no bueno! I'd either change the way you're doing something, so that you won't have this situation, or if you have to, then use blocks (and I agree, block would be the ideal if nothing is accessed that has the potential to be nilled) with references to something that won't be nilled, like a singleton or something.

Comment: You are correct. If he is trying to access data from a deallocated self thus self will be nil OR a possible ref count if he won't use weak self, but he is still has the opportunity to keep on his logic.
Copying the data or using a singleton could be a possible solution.